# Firebase how to make this kind of query in Swift

Tags: json, swift, firebase

I have this JSON structure:

```
{

  "groups" : {
    "-KBxo9-RoY0eowWKeHkU" : {
      "author" : "rsenov",
      "members" : {
        "-KBxo7ZU6McsmDOxyias" : true,
        "-KBxo8_TUTW6NZze6xcd" : true,
        "rsenov" : true
      },
      "name" : "Prueba 3"
    }
  },
  "users" : {
    "-KBxo7ZU6McsmDOxyias" : {
      "avatar" : "owl2",
      "groups" : {
        "-KBxo9-RoY0eowWKeHkU" : true
      },
      "isUser" : false,
      "name" : "Pepa"
    },
    "-KBxo8_TUTW6NZze6xcd" : {
      "avatar" : "monkey",
      "groups" : {
        "-KBxo9-RoY0eowWKeHkU" : true
      },
      "isUser" : false,
      "name" : "Lolas"
    },
    "rsenov" : {
      "avatar" : "guest",
      "groups" : {
        "-KBxo9-RoY0eowWKeHkU" : true
      },
      "isUser" : true,
      "name" : "Ruben",
    }
  }
}
```

and the security&rules file is:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true,
    "users": {
      ".indexOn": ["email", "groups"]
    },
    "groups": {
      ".indexOn": ["author", "name"]
    }
  }
}
```

I'm trying to run a query in order to get the ChildChanged snapshot:

```
DataService.dataService.USERS_REF.queryOrderedByChild("groups").queryEqualToValue(currentGroup.groupKey).observeEventType(.ChildChanged, withBlock: {snapshot in
        print(snapshot)
    })
```

`DataService.dataService.USERS_REF`corresponds to the url that point to the "users" key, and `currentGroup.groupKey`is equal to `-KBxo9-RoY0eowWKeHkU`in this case.

According to this query, I should get the snapshot of the child that has changed. For example, if I replace the user name "Pepa" to "Test", I should get the snapshot:

```
"-KBxo7ZU6McsmDOxyias" : {
  "avatar" : "owl2",
  "groups" : {
    "-KBxo9-RoY0eowWKeHkU" : true
  },
  "isUser" : false,
  "name" : "Test"
}
```

but this query never get's called...
Is there something wrong in my query?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen any idea about that? Would appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

"I'm trying to run a query in order to get the ChildChanged snapshot:" is a little odd.

You can query for data, or observe a node via ChildChanged.

If you just want to be notified of changes within the users node, add an observer to that node and when Pepa changes to Test, your app will be notified and provided a snapshot of the user node that changed.

```
var ref = Firebase(DataService.dataService.USERS_REF)

ref.observeEventType(.ChildChanged, withBlock: { snapshot in
    println("the changed user is: \(snapshot.value)")
})
```

Oh, and no need for queryOrderedByChild since the snapshot will only contain the single node that changed.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I know that it's possible to observe a node that changes in USERS_REF, but the problem is that there will be a lot of users in different devices making changes, and I don't want every user to get notifications when something changes in USERS_REF, only the ones that concern to their user and group. Thats why somehow I have to get only the child changed for the users that belong an specific group with something like `DataService.dataService.USERS_REF.queryOrderedByChild("groups").queryEqualToValue(currentGroup.groupKey)`

Comment: I see. Pretty simple solution: query for all the users in your group and then add observers to just those user nodes.

Comment: Or... and check this out: Create a groups node and in that node have a list of groups which each contain children (user_d's) that refer back to the users node. /groups/some_group_name/uid_0: user name. Then each user can just observe their group node, and when user name changes, they will be notified.

Comment: I already have a group node that have a list of groups that contains the user_id's. You can see it in my JSON structure. I think the better solution is your first option

Comment: Yes, yes you do! I was suggesting making the users name part of that node instead of in the users node so you could change the name there, which would fire the childChanged event.